# What Laplace transformation is used for this?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

[image: a Laplace transformation]

I cannot see the transition here. I was unable to find what Laplace transformation was used here.

Comment: Right now I have found something in Wikipedia  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems Is it "Frequency domain differentiation"?

Comment: The idea there is that just as multiplying with $s$ in the state domain corresponds to differentiation in the time domain, differentation in the state domain corresponds to multiplication with $-t$ in the time domain. So you can differentiate by doing an inverse laplace transform, then multiplying with $-t$, and finally doing a forward laplace transform. And since laplace transforms are linear, you can then pull that "-" out.

Comment: Just look at the definition of the Laplace transform.  A derivative with respect to the frequency variable ($s$) corresponds to a multiplication by the time variable ($t$) with a minus sign, because $(d/ds)e^{-st}=-te^{-st}$.

Comment: The specific function ($\tan^{-1}(1/s)$) is irrelevant; the equation would hold for any $F(s)$.